# How can I convert a NOT IN statement to a NOT EXISTS statement in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I heard that `NOT IN` should be avoided at all costs, so I am updating my queries to utilize `NOT EXISTS` and run `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on them to see if there are any improvements but I am having a hard time wrapping my head around it. How can I convert a query like this:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM customers c
WHERE c.status NOT IN
    ('DELETED', 'ARCHIVED', 'EXPIRED'')
```

Comment: "I heard that `NOT IN` should be avoided at all costs" - where have you heard that? I don't agree with that statement. **Remember that all generalizations are wrong, including this one!**

Comment: "At all costs" was probably an over-statement, I should have worded that more carefully. It was more of a "be careful when using `not in`" type of advice

Comment: Actually for you query mentioned in question NOT IN is good enough. exist clause is better when you are using sub query in where clause to check the existence of value

Comment: @AkhileshMishra the actual query has a bit more crowded `in` and `not in` statements but I did not want to post the original without obfuscating everything in it, so I posted a simplified version

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of postgres optimisation but IME with other products the issues with `NOT IN` are usually associated with `NOT IN (sub_query)` especially if the sub_query can return `NULL`.

Comment: One liner answer for all your queries is `NOT IN` is good when you have a static set of values (as in question) But NOT EXIST is always good when you want to check it through any sub query.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra That makes perfect sense, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have heard the rule incompletely.  This is false:

> I heard that NOT IN should be avoided at all costs, . . .

This is much closer to being true:

> I heard that NOT IN *with a subquery* should be avoided at all costs, . . .

There are two reasons for this.  By far the more important has to do with the handling of `NULL` values.  If *any* value returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then `NOT IN` *never* returns `TRUE`.  That is, the query returns no rows (if this is the only condition).

On the other hand, `NOT EXISTS` does what you expect in this case, essentially ignoring `NULL` values in the subquery.

This is not an issue with explicit lists, because it is unlikely that you will include a `NULL` value in an explicit list.

The second issue is performance.  Some databases will optimize `NOT EXISTS` with a subquery much better than `NOT IN` -- particularly if the appropriate indexes are available.

Answer (score 1):

That might be true if you're using `not in` with nested select, for example:

```
select id
from customer c
where c.status_id not in (
    select id
    from status s
    where s.type = 'DELETED'
)
```

This should rather be rewritten to:

```
select id
from customer c
where not exists(
    select *
    from status s
    where (s.id, s.type) = (c.status_id, 'DELETED')
)
```

But since you're using `not in` with a set of possible values, it's ok and it would be even hard to rewrite it using `exists`.

Comment: I'll admit I've never seen the syntax `where (s.id, s.type) = (c.status_id, 'DELETED')` before - is that unique to Postgres?

Comment: @Dai it's a bit more compact. That's the same as `s.id = c.status_id and s.type = 'DELETED'`

Comment: @Dai yes, that's a postgres' thing. You may upvote in case you've learned something useful;>

Answer (score 0):

> I heard that `NOT IN` should be avoided at all costs.

You have heard incorrectly - and you're applying something you don't understand (or something that you accept at face-value without any investigation on your part) in production. What you're professing is an example of [Cargo-Cult Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Don't do this. Don't believe anything you read without citations and sources (this applies to everything in life, btw)

Anyway, `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` are not semantically equivalent: `IN` (and `NOT IN`) when used with variadic literal values or variadic parameters is just syntactic-sugar for a repeating `OR` statement, whereas `NOT EXISTS` is a test for set-membership, which is a very different operation.

In your case, this:

```
WHERE c.status NOT IN ('DELETED', 'ARCHIVED', 'EXPIRED')
```

Is *semantically identical* to this:

```
WHERE NOT ( c.status = 'DELETED' OR c.status = 'ARCHIVED' OR c.status = 'EXPIRED' )
```

...such an expression *cannot* be simplified and I would argue it's optimal.

Ergo: no changes to this query are needed.